# R - Display unique values in a column rather than count them, within summarize (dplyr pipe)

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape

I would like to reshape my data in a way that district values in one column, related to another column, are displayed in newly created columns

```
df
     A    B  
1  <NA> <NA>
2    a    b
3    a    d
4    b    c
```

similar to :

```
> df %>% 
+   group_by(A) %>% 
+   summarise(n_distinct(B))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
     A     `n_distinct(B)`
   <chr>           <int>
  1 a                   2
  2 b                   1
  3 NA                  1
```

But instead of counting the occurrences, just display the actual values in a new column?

something like the below:

```
df
     A    B
1   <NA> <NA>
2    a    b  **d**
4    b    c
```

I tried spreading, but It is not working, the below error comes up:

> Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows

both my columns are factors, but can be reclassified if need be .

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% group_by(A) %>% summarise(B=paste0(unique(B), collapse = ',')) %>% 
       separate(B,into = paste0('B',1:2))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
A     B1    B2   
<chr> <chr> <chr>
1 a     b     d    
2 b     c     NA   
3 NA    NA    NA   
Warning message:
Expected 2 pieces. Missing pieces filled with `NA` in 2 rows [2, 3].
```

Comment: @SapirGreenberg, Then please update your question with the new data and the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using `spread` after creating a sequence column

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
   group_by(A)  %>% 
   mutate(n1 = paste0("B", row_number())) %>%
   ungroup %>% 
   spread(n1, B)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  A     B1    B2   
#  <fct> <fct> <fct>
#1 a     b     d    
#2 b     c     <NA> 
#3 <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(A = c(NA, 'a', 'a', 'b'), B = c(NA, 'b', 'd', 'c'))
```

Comment: Incredible!! Thank you so much! this is exactly what i wanted to achieve. @akrun